# Updating a SSAS partition slice in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssas, olap, partitioning, rolap

I have an SSAS cube that has two partitions, one in MOLAP and the other in ROLAP.  On my ROLAP partition, I have the slice set with the last 5 members of my Time dimension.  Each night when the cube is processed, I need to update the slice for my ROLAP partition to include the 5 most recent members in my time dimension.

For example, if my cube has a partition slice of:

```
 {[Time].[100], [Time].[101], [Time].[102], [Time].[103], [Time].[104]}
```

After processing, I want to update the slice to become

```
 {[Time].[101], [Time].[102], [Time].[103], [Time].[104], [Time].[105]}
```

Is this possible to achieve this programmatically so that it is possible to include it as a step in my SSIS package?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do to do this is to use XMLA with ascmd.  ascmd is similar to sqlcmd in that it is a command line tool which also allows parameters.  This way you can specify parameters for the [Time].[xxx] values.